# Peering AWS VPC private to NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have two VPC's in VPC1 in public subnet there is NAT GAteway for private subnet to go to internet... in VPC2 private subnet I have EC2 instance that needs to go to internet but i don't want to put NAT gateway or NAT instance in the public subnet of VPC2 if there is a way to sent traffic through peering and use NAT gateway in VPC1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not supported as VPC peering is **not transitive** as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html#transitive-peering):

> If either VPC in a peering relationship has one of the following connections, you **cannot extend** the peering relationship to that connection:
>
> - An **internet connection in a private subnet through a NAT device**

Also:

> Similarly, if VPC A has a **NAT device** that provides internet access to instances in private subnets in VPC A, instances in **VPC B cannot use the NAT device to access the interne**t.

Comment: After two years, we stay with same limitations? I need to do the same thing.